# What is the motivation of studying $P[A]$ in operator K-theory?

Tags: operator-algebras, topological-k-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I am reading the last chapter of Murphy's *$C^*$-algebras and operator theory*. He defines 
$$P[A]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{p\in M_n(A):\text {$p$ is a projection} \}$$
and construct the Grothendieck group $K_0$ on it. But he doesn't explain why $P[A]$, the set of projections, is of particular interest in studying $K$-theory.
What is the motivation of studying $P[A]$ in operator K-theory? Why is the set of projection matrices so important to us?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Projections correspond to vector bundles. You should at least browse a book like Rosenberg's "Introduction to K-Theory" or Max Karoubi's book on the same subject.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I know that  finitely generated projective modules over the C*-algebra C(X) that corresponds to  vector bundles(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem), but what is the relation between projections matrices and  finitely generated projective modules?

Comment: Every finitel generated projective module is isomorphic to the image of an idempotent map $p:A^n\to A^n$ for some $n$.